# How to exclude test files from vue cli build(using vue.config.js)?

Tags: unit-testing, vuejs2, vue-cli, webpack-loader

There is no importing test codes. But the build process includes testing node modules(chai, sinon, nise...).

[image]

I added codes below on vue.config.js to exclude test files from build. (vue-cli-service build)

```js
chainWebpack: (config) => {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
        config.module.rule('ts').exclude.add(/\.test\.ts$/);
    }
},
```

After adding this code, I got warnings like this.
[image]

Is there any solution to exclude test files from build without warning??

Comment: But why? Are your test files linked to your source files? Will the build process actually process the test files?

Comment: @MaartenVeerman Yes, the build process includes test files and node modules (sinon, chai). There is no importing test code.

Answer (score 0):

If tests are passing with a test command, the issue might be that tests are not excluded within the `tsconfig` used for the build (?).